# Ошибка компиляции(JSON) - Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: json, xcode, swift

Выдает ошибку

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

В следующей строке кода

```
if let json = JSON(data: data).array {
```

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я делаю видеоуроки от Udemy, так там такая ошибка не возникает!
Знаю Что можно обрамить в конструкцию do-catch c ключевым словом try, но не понятно почему у меня возникает ошибка, а у ведущего с урока, без добавления данной конструкции, такая ошибка не возникает. Плюс ко всему обрамление добавляет новые ошибки в код.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, что бы данная ошибка не возникала?

Вот весь код файла:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class MessageService {

static let instance = MessageService()

var channels = [Channel]()
var messages = [Message]()
var selectedChannel : Channel?


func findAllChannel(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    Alamofire.request(URL_GET_CHANNELS, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: BEARER_HEADER).responseJSON{ (response) in
        if response.result.error == nil {
            guard let data = response.data else {return}
           do{
            if let json = try JSON(data:data).array {
                for item in json {
                    let name = item["name"].stringValue
                    let channelDescription = item["description"].stringValue
                    let id = item["_id"].stringValue
                    let channel = Channel(channelTitle: name, channelDescription: channelDescription, id: id)
                    self.channels.append(channel)
                }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NOTIF_CHANNELS_LOADED, object: nil)
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion (false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }


           } catch let error as NSError {

            }
         }
      }
   }

func findAllMessageForChannel(channelId: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler ){
    Alamofire.request("\(URL_GET_MESSAGES)\(channelId)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: BEARER_HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in


        if response.result.error == nil {
            self.clearMessages()
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            if let json = JSON(data: data).array {
                for item in json {
                    let messageBody = item["messageBody"].stringValue
                    let channelId = item["channelId"].stringValue
                    let id = item["_id"].stringValue
                    let userName = item["userName"].stringValue
                    let userAvatar = item["userAvatar"].stringValue
                    let userAvatarColor = item["userAvatarColor"].stringValue
                    let timeStamp = item["timeStamp"].stringValue

                    let message = Message(message: messageBody, userName: userName, channelId: channelId, userAvatar: userAvatar, userAvatarColor: userAvatarColor, id: id, timeStamp: timeStamp)
                    self.messages.append(message)
                }
                print(self.messages)
                completion(true)
            }
        else {
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            completion(false)
             }
            }
        }
}

func clearMessages() {
    messages.removeAll()
}

func clearChannels() {
    channels.removeAll()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в первой функции написано как надо, во второй то же самое нужно делать:

```
 do {
       if let json = try JSON(data:data).array {
           for item in json {
                let messageBody = item["messageBody"].stringValue
                let channelId = item["channelId"].stringValue
                let id = item["_id"].stringValue
                let userName = item["userName"].stringValue
                let userAvatar = item["userAvatar"].stringValue
                let userAvatarColor = item["userAvatarColor"].stringValue
                let timeStamp = item["timeStamp"].stringValue

                let message = Message(message: messageBody, userName: userName, channelId: channelId, userAvatar: userAvatar, userAvatarColor: userAvatarColor, id: id, timeStamp: timeStamp)
                self.messages.append(message)
            }
            print(self.messages)
            completion(true)
       }
   } catch let error as NSError {
         debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
         completion(false)
   }
```

Comment: Да я знаю, что написано, это я написал. К тому же в видео уроке нет такой конструкции в данном случае, поэтому меня мучает вопрос почему у автора видео все работает и без конструкции "do - try - catch", а у меня с данной конструкцией не запускается приложение! Подскажите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста!

Comment: да не будет это работать без try - catch, это throw функция, то есть которая может вернуть ошибку, а такие функции работают только через try catch. В каком видео уроке? ссылку хотя бы оставляйте.

Comment: "Хотя бы"?!?!? ссылку могу оставить на ресурс - https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5432878 - В шестом разделе - "06-networking-apis-rest-and-building-a-slack-clone", номер урока, извините к сожалению, не помню. Где-то посредине раздела, ближе к концу. Там все наглядно видно, видно как БЕЗ этой конструкции у автора все работает! ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ!

Comment: Нашел! Извините, что так, но в шестом разделе - "06-networking-apis-rest-and-building-a-slack-clone", 078 видео, на 9 минуте 30-ой секунде, видно как он прописывает строку о которой шла речь и ошибка не возникает, максимум предупреждение.! Потом он запускает программу и все работает и без вышеозначенной конструкции try catch! Еще раз ссылка на ресурс - rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5432878